# Upgrading memory in Lenovo Ideapad FLEX 14-IWL

Tags: windows-10, memory, lenovo-laptop, task-manager

I want to upgrade the RAM in my Lenovo [Ideapad FLEX 14-IWL](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/c340-14_flex-14_hmm_201903.pdf) (mtm #  81SQ0008US). Task manager shows as 1 of 2 slot used, but Lenovo says there is only one slot, and maximum ram is 32 for it. I am not sure what is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer is correct.

Many controllers may provide multiple slots - that being what the software identifies - but that does not mean they're always physically installed and/or user accessible.

Comment: Pages 37-38 of the Hardware Manual (linked in your question) shows there's only one memory module slot. Evidently Lenovo reused a chip from another design which had two memory module slots on it, but this Ideapad only has one physical slot.